# SWT Tree and TreeItem: Change the color of the expand/collapse indicator

Tags: java, tree, swt

Environment: SWT

Widget: `Tree` and `TreeItem`

How do I go about changing the color of the expand/collapse node indicator?
(Are those images, Unicode characters, or rendered graphics?)

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046620) here on StackOverflow, but although he asked the question, his aim was different, hence the accepted solution was to the real question (not selecting the root node). I have no such need to limit selections.

The only other possibly related question that I saw was the one [about a Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814087) (I am using SWT) `JTree` and changing the horizontal line colors. I am not after lines, just the expand/collapse indicator (image?).

Why? The collapse/expand indicators are near impossible to see on the needed background color.

Ideally, I would like to be able to set the color at run time.

There are 3 indicators that I can see:

- Not selected open
- Not selected closed
- Selected open

[image]

Comment: The expand indicator is drawn by the native control that SWT uses for the tree. There does not appear to be a way for SWT to change the color.

Comment: The solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832014/swt-tree-lowering-the-native-expand-icon-possible) seems to be able to draw on top of the expand/collapse icon on Windows. Doesn't work properly on Linux though.